# Shotwell EXIF of generated JPEGs from RAW (NEF in this case)

Tags: shotwell

I've noticed that after you double click on a raw image (NEF for me) in shotwell it produces a jpeg file. Before double clicking if I looked at View > Extended Information (EXIF) it showed correctly, but after jpeg is generated, there is no EXIF data available, so one has to open the file browser and navigate to the original NEF photo in order to look at the EXIF data.

Is there a way to program (am I missing something?) shotwell to retrieve the EXIF from the NEF files after the jpegs are generated?

Answer (score 1):

First see if [this bug](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4149) is affecting you, where Shotwell is using the small embedded jpeg from the NEF instead of the paired (higher-resolution) jpeg. Are the these jpeg files very low quality?

If not, check that you have Shotwell set to write metadata to files in Edit/Preferences like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I missed that Metadata option in the Edit/Preferences. But it seems that even with the option checked it's not updating the EXIF data in JPEGs. When I double click on a newly imported RAW file, it generates a JPEG file (and with that option checked) it does show a progress bar and says that it's writing some metadata, but when I look at the extended information at the JPEG files it gives no information on lens.. etc.

I am not affected by that bug and I'm not shooting RAW+JPEG, just RAW, and the JPEG is generated by Shotwell.

Comment: @razvanc I have a Nikon too and I just tried this. I can confirm that this is the same on my machine. I can't find any info on why this is on Shotwell's site, so I recommend filing a bug / feature request. How-to is on their FAQ page here: http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellFAQ You can also give Darktable a try, to work directly on the NEF files. Both programs are great but neither does everything I want.

Comment: Thanks for your time and pointing me in the right direction.